# SWift 4 JSONDecoder decode from Alamofire response

Tags: swift, alamofire, swift4, jsondecoder

I have a structure that contains another structures and arrays.

```
public struct Report: Codable {
 let s:Student;
 let vio:[VIO];
 let  stuPresence: [StuPresence]; 
}
```

I am trying new `JSONDecoder()` to transform alamofire response into my struct.

```
sessionManager.request( self.url_report+"?d="+date, method: .get, parameters: nil).responseJSON{ response in
    if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
            debugPrint(response)
            do{
                let r = try JSONDecoder().decode(Report.self, from: response.result.value as! Data)
                debugPrint(r);
            }catch{
               self.showMessage(message: self.general_err)
            }
    }
}
```

The problem is that instead of strings after decoding in my `Report` struct I get numbers (checked from debugging mode). What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: it also gives error

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x108011508) to 'NSData' (0x108010090)
```

Comment: response.data instead of response.result.value

Comment: after these changes I end up in the `catch` block

Comment: the problem could be in the models ,can you give a son sample and models structure in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear:

`response.result.value` is obviously a dictionary (`__NSDictionaryI`) which cannot be casted to `(NS)Data`. That means that the JSON is already deserialized.

To be able to use `JSONDecoder` you have to change your `Alamofire` settings to return raw `Data`

Comment: Any suggestions how to make return raw Data?  I tried many variations and always end up in `catch` block.

Comment: What error do you get following the suggestion in the comments (`response.data`)? You don't even handle the actual error.

Comment: If you end up in the `catch` block there is an `error`. `print` it. `self.general_err` is pointless. Never ignore `error`s passed in a `catch` block.

Comment: `Error info: valueNotFound(Swift.Int, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "s", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected Int value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: Your created structs don't match the JSON. The error message says that in the `Student` struct the value for key `id` is `nil`. The `Alamofire` part is working.

Comment: Actually it's correct since the server sends some values `nil`. in my `struct` do I need to markup it somehow to make some fields nullable?

Comment: Just make the property optional `let id : Int?`

Comment: It Worked! Thanks A lot! Quick question if in my struct I have field that JSON doesn't contain is there a chance to avoid error?

Comment: Use CodingKeys and leave the key out. Assign a default value to the property or make it optional.